# How to write a code for each array within an array

Tags: php, json, api, loops, foreach

I am new to this so please do not judge.

1. I have transformed a .csv file into an `array([0]=>array([0]=>string(), [1]=>string())[1]=>array([0]=>string(), [1]=>string())` etc. So I can access it numerically i.e. `$the_big_array[1][1]`
2. Now I want the program to write a couple of lines of code for each array within an array.
3. Basically what I am doing is creating a table like this that will be encoded in json.

   `$request['AddPrice'][0][variable1] = $the_big_array[1][2]`
   `$request['AddPrice'][0][variable2] = $the_big_array[1][3]`

and I want different values loaded for and from each line of .csv `file/$the_big_array`

```
$request['AddPrice'][1][variable1] = $the_big_array[1][2]
$request['AddPrice'][1][variable2] = $the_big_array[1][3]
```

I am stuck at foreach function as I cannot grasp how to make it execute certain action for each array within an array.

Comment: it's not  too clear , can you print a short part of the array to see the structure ?

Comment: Hey Pawel, it would be helpful if you could show a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of your arrays to improve clarity, and show us what you've tried so far (code) so we can help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a foreach loop for every array dimension.
If You have 2 dimensions, like in $the_big_array[1][1], go through the first dimension with your first loop. Inside this loop, do another foreach to go through your second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

so I have fixed this problem. Perhaps the question was not clear enough.

What I did was to create arrays with maximum occupancy for each of my rooms and add nested foreachloop for each occupancy, so it has to repeat until maximum occupancy is reached and only then it can iterate to the next key in the first foreachloop.